# Binding "mouseover" events to points on a line in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, visualization

I would like to get the coordinates of a point on a line by clicking on the line using the following code:

```
var lineData = [ { "x": 1,   "y": 5},  { "x": 20,  "y": 20},
                 { "x": 40,  "y": 10}, { "x": 60,  "y": 40},
                 { "x": 80,  "y": 5},  { "x": 100, "y": 60}];

var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
    .interpolate("linear");

var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 200)
    .attr("height", 200);

var lineGraph = svgContainer.append("path")
    .data([lineData]).attr("d", lineFunction)
  //.attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))  
    .attr("stroke", "blue")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .on('mousedown', function(d) {
        console.log({"x":d.x, "y":d.y})
    });
```

(I updated the code to address the comments, but I still get "Object {x: undefined, y: undefined}")

I keep getting an "undefined" when clicking on the line. Am I missing a step?

Comment: You never bound your lineData to the path, like .append("path").data([lineData]).attr("d", lineFunction)

Comment: This won't really help though, because you'd have access to the mouse's coordinates but you don't get the point on the path.

Comment: I believe that's an answer @enjalot.  Not a comment

Comment: I updated the code snippet, but still get "undefined"

Comment: d would be lineData, which is your array. you won't know which point was closest to the click without calculating it yourself from the mouse coordinates.

Answer (score 6):

You can get the coordinates of an event using [`d3.event`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-d3_event):

```
.on("mousedown", function() {
    console.log({"x": d3.event.x, "y": d3.event.y});
});
```

Comment: This gives you the x,y coordinates relative to the SVG, but ignores the coordinates specified by the axes (and hence the x,y coordinates that are used to define the line). I could presumably map these SVG coordinates back to the coordinates used to define the axes, but it seems like there should be a more natural solution, one that doesn't entail so much work ?

Comment: For my actual problem, the x-axis is based on the Date, and all the x components of the line are Date objects, so it's not clear how to map the "x" pixel location to a date?

Comment: The scales have `invert()` functions that you can give an output value to to get the input value. And no, there's no way of getting these values directly. It's only two more function calls though.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I know this is old question but I'm having one issue with `d3.event.x` & `d3.event.y`. I'm getting values for both as __undefined__ in Mozilla Firefox 23.

Comment: Unfortunately these things are not consistent across browsers -- you can try `.clientX` or `.pageX` instead.

Answer (score 3):

use mouse event

```
.on('mousedown', function(d) {
    var m = d3.mouse(this);
    console.log("x:"+m[0]+" y:"+m[1]);
});
```

in your function m[0] and m[1] gives you X and Y.